# Is it allowed with MVVM to run a RoutedEventArgs event in the xaml.cs?

Tags: c#

For example, if I want to implement a GridViewColumnHeader MenuItem.Click, can I do so in the xaml.cs?

```
   <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
    "{Binding Path=LastName}" 
    Width="100">
    <GridViewColumnHeader>Last Name
        <GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu  MenuItem.Click="LastNameCM_Click"  
                      Name="LastNameCM">
            <MenuItem Header="Ascending" />
            <MenuItem Header="Descending" />
        </ContextMenu>
        </GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
     </GridViewColumnHeader>
   </GridViewColumn>
```

Ok I do it now this way, Thanks for help:

```
      AscendingUserIdClicked = new RelayCommand(OrderByUserId);
      DescendingUserIdClicked=new RelayCommand(OrderByDescendingUserId);

     private void OrderByUserId(object parameter)
     {
        AscUserIdIsChecked = true;
        DescUserIdIsChecked = false;
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>(Users.OrderBy(x => x.UserId));
     }
     private void OrderByDescendingUserId(object parameter)
     {
        AscUserIdIsChecked = false;
        DescUserIdIsChecked = true;
        Users = new ObservableCollection<User>(Users.OrderByDescending(x => x.UserId));
     }
```

And at Xaml:

```
     <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding UserId}"  Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader>UserId
                        <GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Ascending" Command="{Binding AscendingUserIdClicked}" IsChecked="{Binding AscUserIdIsChecked}"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Descending" Command="{Binding DescendingUserIdClicked}" IsChecked="{Binding DescUserIdIsChecked}"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </GridViewColumnHeader.ContextMenu>
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: In certain cases writing code in xaml.cs is unavoidable(or it is lot of trouble to write pure MVVM).

Comment: ...but in this case you can just specify a command in your MenuItems and use a binding to a corresponding ICommand (or derivative) property in your viewmodel. That approach would certainly be preferrable to working with the click-event in the code-behind of your view.

Comment: Thank you, so if I understood you correctly, you mean this :                           <MenuItem Header="Ascending" Command="{Binding AscendingUserIdClicked}"/>
<MenuItem Header="Descending" Command="{Binding DescendingUserIdClicked}"/>

Comment: @Karsaorlong1981: Yes , that is exactly what I meant.